# 'val_accuracy' and 'val_acc' both giving error when used for plotting learning curve in keras

Tags: tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, plot, deep-learning

I was getting an error by using acc and val_acc in keras, so I searched on stack overflow and got an answer saying that try changing acc to accuracy and val_acc to value_accuracy.

My initial code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

After changing it :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

I am still getting error for val_accuracy even though plt.plot(history.history['accuracy']) line was corrected.
Is there any method to fix it?

For reference my Entire code is given below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv('mobile_price_ranger_train.csv')
X = df.iloc[:,:-1].values.reshape(-1,20)
y = df.iloc[:,-1].values.reshape(-1,1)


sc = StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X)

ohe = OneHotEncoder()
y = ohe.fit_transform(y).toarray()

# using train_test_split to split the data

X_train, X_test, y_train ,y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2,random_state = 0)



model = Sequential() # created the model

# adding layers
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu', input_dim = 20))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10)

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please do not write in all-bold and do not doubly intend your code snippets (edited).

Answer (score 1):

You must specify `validation_split` or `validation_data` in `model.fit()` method. For example:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.25, epochs=100, batch_size=10)
```

Here I used 25% of data as a validation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `validation_data` in your `model. fit`.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train ,y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                     test_size=0.2,random_state = 0)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                    epochs=100, batch_size=10)
```